# Unity3D issue with font size near text height

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm facing an issue where a text in the Unity UI does show on my PC, but doesn't show on my smartphone (and the phones of thousands of players actually). The disappearing basically comes from the text-component setting to truncate vertical overflow, but there shouldn't be any vertical overflow in the first place.

So when I have my font size at 24 and the text-component height at 30, it is not a problem on either platform, but once the font size gets "near enough" to the text-component height (but is still lower than it), so in this example let's say 28, then it'll still appear on PC, but not on my phone.

I'm actually not sure, if this has something to do with the phones OS (Android) itself, or with the DPI and the scaling of the canvas with the canvas scaler.

Anyways this is really annoying, so is there a neat way to fix it? I btw. don't want to set all text-components to vertical overflow, because that's not what I intent to do in multiple cases.

Comment: Still using NGUI? Switch to Unity's native uGUI. It doesn't have such problem.

Comment: Okay, then I was wrong using the name NGUI. I'm talking about the UI which you can just create by rightclicking in the hierarchy->UI. Edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is actually to set your *Horizontal* and *Vertical Overflow* to *Overflow* instead of *Truncate*.
This is the safest method that will force all the text from your Text component to render but I don't know why you don't want to use it.

You still have other solution but they are not better than what I said above. Although, they should work.

**1**.If your Text is a mult-line text, decrease the *Line Spacing* values below 1 and that will make more of your Text show.

[image]

**2**.If it is a single-line text, then Enable the *Best Fit* check box then decrease the Min Size and increase the Max Size until you get what you want.

[image]

Comment: Yea I could use the Best Fit, but it is also not what I intend to do, when multiple texts (in different locations and some multiline, some singleline) should have the same fontsize.
I think line spacing can also not be the reason, because the cases I'm talking about happen on singleline text.